# What is the actual memory capacity of my laptop?

Tags: memory

According to the HP site, my i7-4610M HP zBook will only support 16GB RAM :(.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/workstations/zbook-17.html

However, the specs for that processor according to Intel indicate that it supports 32GB.

http://ark.intel.com/products/80345/Intel-Core-i7-4610M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz

In addition, the manual for the zBook says:

The computer has four memory slots. Expansion memory slots are located in a compartment
on the bottom of the computer. Primary memory slots are located under the keyboard.

So, it could potentially use an 8GBx4 configuration without the need to support 16GB chips.  I want to place an order to expand my memory to its' max. capacity.  Should I get 2 or 4 8GB modules?

Comment: Where on the first link do you see it being restricted to 16 GB of RAM? I cannot find any such reference, even searching for the string, "16".

Comment: The link is for the 2015 ZBook. You have the 2013 ZBook. The specs for the 2015 are totally irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, if you expand the section "Full specs for **G2**" you see :  32 GB maximum memory with quad-core processor. 16 GB maximum memory with dual-core processor.  And the "Available processors section in those full specs, "Intel® Core™ i7-4610M with Intel HD Graphics 4600 (3 GHz, up to 3.7 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 4 MB cache, **2 cores**) @ChrisInEdmonton

Answer (score 0):

I did post a few links to the research I had done, and clarified one commenter's confusion about them, so I don't understand the downvoting of this question.  However, with *further* research, this turned out to be really easy to determine, even without an external utility.  From a command prompt, simply type:

```
wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
```

which produced the following output for my new laptop:

```
MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices
16777216     2
```

Answer (score -1):

The link you posted says the maximum memory is 64gb:

[image]

The maximum supported by your processor is 32 GB:

[image]

You always have to go with your biggest limitation which in this case is the processor. So you are able to get DDR3L 1333 or DDR3L 1600 at a maximum capacity of 32 GB total. This means that your 4 sticks of 8 GB (8 x 4 = 32) would indeed work.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered his question correctly with explanation.